# Angular2 reusing service from lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-services, angular-module

Situation looks like this: I have lazy loaded module ModuleA with RouterModule imported/exported with forChild. In ModuleA i have service ServiceA which turned out to be usable in another lazy loaded module ModuleB. I would like to reuse ServiceA and from what I know the preferred solution is to register it globally by creating ModuleA.forRoot and importing it in CoreModule. But this way I am also importing ModuleARoutingModule into CoreModule which then causes strange behaviour in router.

Temporarily i provided ServiceA directly in ComponentB in ModuleB without touching ModuleA - it is only imported in AppRoutingModule.loadChildren.

This solution seems to be against importing services in different components but I don't know how to do it differently. One solution that comes to my mind is dividing ModuleA into ModuleA and ModuleAServices and then import ModuleAServces globally.

Comment: lazy loading is for independent modules. it sounds like module B depends on module A, as such, this module A service probably doesn't really belong to module A, but is more shared / core module territory.